# Powershell, have function return variable that stores it?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-v4.0

Is it possible to have a function return the name of the variable that stores it?

i.e $a = myFunction

and have the function know that it is held in $a, when $a is dynamically assigned to it in a shell?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?!? It doesn't seem to make a lot of sense...

Comment: @Massimo If someone runs a function, they may have to pass some other output into a different function. Being able to access the variable the original function is stored in will 'remind' them of what they need to type :-)

Comment: This... makes even less sense.

Comment: @benignadmin = Can you show us an example, even if in pseudocode, of what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function test() {
    write-Host "Called by: $($MyInvocation.Line)"
}

$a = test
```

Which outputs

```
Called by:     $a = test
```

?

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I needed. Thanks! I upvoted you. Not enough rep points to make it show, unfortunately.

Comment: @benignadmin http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: V.nice! I imagine that may be quite a useful little trick for both debugging and logging.

Comment: FYI, this tells you the *line* of code where the function was called; which might or might not include assigning its result to a variable, or could contain anything else entirely; just try calling that function with `if(test -eq $null) { ... }`, or similar constructs.

Comment: And also please keep in mind that, even in your case, $a will not be assigned until the function returns; any action on $a while inside the function *will operate on the previous value of $a* (if any), and $a will be overwritten with the actual return value of the function after it ends.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. You can save $MyInvocation is a $global variable to keep it more permanent.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible at all, nor would it make much sense.

It's like expecting the integer `42` to know if it has been stored in the variable `$answer`.

---

Once a function returns, only its return value (if any) is stored in a variable (if an assignment is actually used). If `Get-Answer` returns `42` and you issue the command `$answer = Get-Answer`, then `$answer` will indeed contain `42`, but no record will be kept of the fact that it was stored there by having it returned from a function; for all intents and purposes, the end results of `$answer = 42` and `$answer = Get-Answer` are identical, if `Get-Answer` does indeed return `42`.

Also, the assignement (if any) only happens *after* a function returns; the function only provides a return value (if it does); it doesn't and shouldn't care what PowerShell is going to do with this value after it returns; and its return value could very well be discarded instead of being assigned to anything. There is no direct link between `$answer` and `Get-Answer`: what PowerShell does when faced with a command like `$answer = Get-Answer` is:

- Execute `Get-Answer`
- Grab the return value from `Get-Answer`
- Store this value in `$answer`

None of the players has any knowledge of this link; the function doesnt know what its return value will be used for, and the variable doesn't know where its assigned value comes from.

And even if some record was kept of this assignment having ever happened, it definitely wouldn't have happened yet while `Get-Answer` was still being executed.

Comment: Get-Variable | Where {$_.Value -eq "42"} is one way to do that. If variables held time stamps or properties of the function that created them, it would be more useful.

Comment: @benignadmin see my update.

Comment: Think outside of the box. Typing in '$thisvar=thisFunction' following by typing $^ outputs $thisvar literally.

Comment: That's only the shell telling you the last thing you typed. This doesn't have anything to do with actual processing.

Comment: The last thing you type before you put a function in a variable is.... what exactly? It's literally the last thing you typed.

Comment: +1 for the HGTTG reference alone, plus the actual content!

Answer (score 0):

With the minimal info you've shared, this is the best guess I could make.
I'm going largely on your statement of "pass some other output into a different function"

```
myFunction1 {
    ...code...
    return $someThing
}

myFunction2 {
    param ($param1)
    ...code...
}
```

Usage

```
$a = myFunction1
myFunction2 $a
```

Be aware that echo's or write-hosts cmds within a function are ALSO return values. Use write-debug for debug info, or if you really need that info "returned" return is as an array (or a custom object)

```
return @($var1, $va2, $var3)
```

Comment: That sounds different that what you first asked about, no mention of a 2nd function. Or is it single function that needs to remember config state settings from the last run? Try having the function use "$cachedSomething = import-clixml" at the top and "export-clixml $cachedSomething X:\network\config.xml" at the end. //poster appears to have deleted comment this response was for//

Comment: Thanks for trying. I guess the best way to say it in terms of powershell is I want something that does this: Get-ParentVariable which would be run inside of a function and simply tell the function what variable it is stored in, which could be returned out of the function.

Comment: @benignadmin this still doesn't make sense: the assignment of the function's return value to a variable is processed only *after* the function returns, thus it doesn't even *exist* until the function completes its execution.

Comment: even it you could do this exactly what would be the point of knowing the variable name you are about to add an object to?